# How do i replace social media links in navbar with icons?

Tags: css, wordpress, icons, sticky, social-media

I have turned on the CSS classes in the Appearance > Menu section.

I have put the social media icon imagery in my Tiny Hestia template img folder, given each one a class and added the below code to my child theme style.css:

```html
.fb-icon a{
 background-image: url(assets/img/fb_icon.png);  
}
  
.ig-icon a{
 background-image: url(assets/img/ig_icon.png); 
}
 
.tw-icon a{
 background-image: url(assets/img/tw_icon.png);  
}
```

My navbar currently looks like it can see the images and is linking them but maybe the format is wrong or it needs some more styling?

[my navbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9eftm.png)

I basically want the social media icons to be part of my sticky navigation and just show as icons (without the text)

Thanks

Comment: The text should then be removed from your html and background-size has to be set to 100% in the css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beside setting the div size (from Invariant Change's post) you also might want to add `font-size:0;` to hide the text and `background-position: center;` so the icon is centered. Also if your icons haven't got the right dimensions to fit a small button you might add `background-size: contain;` or `background-size: 32px;` - the first one doesn't let them overflow, the second let's you set a fixed size.

Edit: I forgot about `background-repeat: no-repeat;` which is quite important as the default behaviour of background-image is repeat (which is good for tiled/pattern backgrounds, not so much for logos). :)

So your resulting code would be:

```
    .fb-icon a {background-image: url(assets/img/fb_icon.png);} 
    .ig-icon a {background-image: url(assets/img/ig_icon.png);}
    .tw-icon a {background-image: url(assets/img/tw_icon.png);}
    .fb-icon a, .ig-icon a, .tw-icon a {
        height:32px;
        width:32px;
        font-size:0;
        background-position: center;
        background-size: contain;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

### Define image width and Size

To get he icons to fit in the navigation bar, you will have to size them to fit correctly.

It's best practice to use HTML `height` and `width`, but if you can get away with just using the CSS `height` and `width`.

**EXMAPLE:**

**Note:** Use the correct image height and width's

```
.fb-icon a{
    background-image: url(assets/img/fb_icon.png);
    height:32px;
    width:32px  
}

.ig-icon a{
    background-image: url(assets/img/ig_icon.png);
    height:32px;
    width:32px  
}
.tw-icon a{
    background-image: url(assets/img/tw_icon.png);
    height:32px;
    width:32px  
}
```

or

```
.fb-icon a, .ig-icon a, .tw-icon a {
        height:32px;
        width:32px  
}
```